# Could not GET 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/androidx/navigation/navigation-safe-args-generator/maven-metadata.xml'

Tags: android, kotlin

static def addRepos(RepositoryHandler handler) {
    handler.google()
    handler.jcenter()
    handler.maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/" }
    handler.maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
    apply from: 'versions.gradle'
    addRepos(repositories)
    dependencies {
        classpath deps.android_gradle_plugin
        classpath deps.kotlin.plugin
        classpath deps.navigation.safe_args_plugin
        classpath deps.hilt_android_gradle_plugin
        classpath deps.firebase.google_services
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

allprojects {
    addRepos(repositories)
    repositories {
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your didn't specify the version number.

```
def nav_version = "2.4.0"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```

Comment: I specify version number in another gradle

Comment: I have no idea please can someone help me?